# Could I use 僕 to refer to myself?

Tags: word-choice

I know the safest pronoun to use in Japanese is always 私, but I like the sound of 僕 and want to know if it would be odd or stupid sounding for me to use it? I'm a teenage girl and a foreigner(obviously). If used only with friends casually, is it weird? I've seen this on the web before but opinions seem very mixed, and a lot is 5+ years old(it seems in my results it least) so I mostly just want opinions.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: Are you aware of the genderedness of 僕?

Comment: If you can read Japanese, Wikipedia has an article about the phenomenon of girls using "boku": https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ボク少女

Comment: This is just trivial, but the reason for ボク少女 is not necessarily a problem of gender identity but (maybe more likely) the fact that girls lack intermediate pronouns before わたし, which may sound too mature for them.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, 僕 is for boys. If you didn't know this, don't use 僕.

However, according to one recent survey, 1.2% of female middle school students actually use 僕 ([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9C%E3%82%AF%E5%B0%91%E5%A5%B3#.E3.83.9C.E3.82.AF.E5.B0.91.E5.A5.B3.E3.81.A8.E7.8F.BE.E5.AE.9F)). About 20 years ago when I was a middle school student, there was one (and only one) girl around me who was using 僕 on a daily basis for some reason. After that, I've met a few people who have gender dysphoria and are using 僕 (or 俺) despite their feminine appearance.

I'd recommend that you do *not* use 僕 unless you are very fluent in Japanese and know what you're really going to do. It is true that a few native female teenagers (in the real world) use 僕 quite naturally, but a foreign teenager girl using 僕 would almost certainly sound simply "incorrect."

In fiction, female users of 僕 are not so uncommon, and it's considered as one of the ways to characterize a person. [This page](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%9C%E3%82%AF%E3%81%A3%E5%A8%98) has a long list of female characters who use 僕 in fiction. Many (but not all) of them are boyish, tomboyish, naive, or have some other outstanding characteristics.