# Why is Lucoa using 僕 when referring to herself?

Tags: first-person-pronouns

I was re-watching Dragon Maid and was wondering why Lucoa is using 僕 even though she's female.

Lucoa: 僕にも演出やらせて、やらせて!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36844/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tomboy sort of thing.  Also, girls that hang around more often with boys sometimes pick that up as a matter of asserting their identity as one of the guys.